Deb postinst files and the installation path
I created some software that gets packaged up in a debian package (.deb file).
To have a launcher I used the postinst maintainer script to execute something like
xdg-desktop-menu install /absolute/path/launcher.desktop

and that works pretty well. But then I noticed you can install the package using
dpkb-deb -x mypackage.deb $TARGET_DIRECTORY

which means the user can choose where the packaged files end up in the filesystem. But how would the postinst script then know from where to install the launcher?
